# How to compare parent child data in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have two SQL tables like below

```
columns of T1: meterID, parentID, childID  
columns of T2: dataID, meterID, date, amount
```

Sample data of tables;

```
      T1                            T2
-------------              -------------------------
1 | null |  2  *           1 | 1 | 01,01,2013 | 100  *
1 | null |  3  *           2 | 2 | 01,01,2013 | 60   *
2 |   1  |  4              3 | 3 | 01,01,2013 | 40   *
2 |   1  |  5              4 | 4 | 01,01,2013 | 35
3 |   1  |  6              5 | 5 | 01,01,2013 | 25
3 |   1  |  7              6 | 6 | 01,01,2013 | 15
4 |   2  | null            7 | 7 | 01,01,2013 | 25
5 |   2  | null
6 |   3  | null  
7 |   3  | null
```

I want to compare if the sum of the children's amount is equal to parent's amount.

For example; meter1 is parent of meter2 and meter3 (lines with *). I want to check if 100 = 60 + 40.
How can i do this with SQL query.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request groups children's and compare to the parent.

```
SELECT t1.meterID, 
       CASE WHEN t1.amount = o.SumAmount THEN 'IsMatch' ELSE 'IsNotMatch' END
FROM T2 t1 OUTER APPLY (
                        SELECT SUM(t3.amount) AS SumAmount
                        FROM T1 t2 JOIN T2 t3 ON t2.childID = t3.meterID
                        WHERE t1.meterID = t2.meterID
                        GROUP BY t2.meterID
                        ) o
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c6d3/1)

after testing: you can use query without GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT t1.meterID, 
       CASE WHEN t1.amount = o.SumAmount THEN 'IsMatch' ELSE 'IsNotMatch' END
FROM T2 t1 OUTER APPLY (
                        SELECT SUM(t3.amount) AS SumAmount
                        FROM T1 t2 JOIN T2 t3 ON t2.childID = t3.meterID
                        WHERE t1.meterID = t2.meterID
                        ) o
```

Comment: thanks for response, your query works but just for 1=2+3. I also want to check if 2=4+5 and 3=6+7 is equal. An image that shows the relation between meters: [IMAGE](http://i.imgbox.com/adwbOfdh.jpg)

Comment: @AhmetEmre90 But this is checked in query: (2=4+5) = (2, IsMatch) and (3=6+7) = (3, IsMatch)

Comment: Ooh, sorry. I thought completely different way. It makes sense now. Thanks for help again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sum up the children amounts and compare to the parent.  This requires two joins to the `t2` table, one for the parent and one for the children.

The following query assumes that `t1` has no duplicated entries:

```
select t1.parentId, t1.childId,
       parent.amount as parent_amount,
       SUM(child.amount) as child_amount,
       (case when parent.amount = SUM(child.amount) then 'Match'
             else 'NoMatch'
        end)
from t1 left outer join
     t2 parent
     on t1.parentId = t2.meterid left outer join
     t3 child
     on t1.childId = t2.meterId
group by t1.parent_id, t1.childId, parent.amount
```